# How do I sync my desktop Simplenote with that on my mobile phone?

Tags: android, sync

1. I have Simplenote on my android phone.
2. I have installed Simplenote on my Ubuntu 20.04 pc (from 'Ubuntu Software').
3. Now, how do I sync the Simplenote on my pc with that on my mobile (Android phone / cell phone)?
   Thank you.
   DB

Answer (score 1):

Generally in Ubuntu: set up a google account in Ubuntu to use features from google. Link syncing bookmarks between systems and gmail.

On the simplenote site they explain how to share notes, so logically I would assume if you tag it with your own mail address it will be shown everywhere you use simplenote with that mail address:

I would assume you use your mail address as a tag:

> [How can I share a note or collaborate with others](https://simplenote.com/help/)?
>
> If you’d like others to view and edit one of your notes, add their email address as a tag. The shared note will then pop up in their list of notes. They’ll need to have their own Simplenote account first. Similarly, if you’d like to work on a note together, have them add your email address as a tag to collaborate. In the iOS app, instead of adding your email address as a tag, you can tap the Info panel icon when viewing a note, then tap Collaborate.

Comment: Thank you. I can make contact by, online, logging-in to my account via simplenote website: 'www.app.simplenote.com ----- However, the simplenote app - downloaded from the Ubuntu Software app store - does not give any option for linking to the web or an email address. Would it help if I downloaded via the Terminal, using terminal commands?